# return a large amount of html (with a couple of variables) via ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have an ajax function search for keywords in a big database. The php being called simply says "no" if there's nothing, but if there are found records, it goes ahead and creates all of the HTML and returns the html, so that AJAX only needs to put the returned text into the html of a div. My problem is that I'd like to pass along a couple of variables, like the number of records found, etc.

So if I tried to put it in a statement that javascript could eval, I'm afraid that not only is all of the html potentially big enough to cause some sort of variable problems, but it also has a lot of single and double quotes, etc, that could unexpectedly end the variable before it's supposed to.  See the following

```
// (I know I don't have a single quote after data and that will break it. This is just an example
echo "{ status: 'success', total: '".count($relevance)."' data: ";
foreach ($relevance as $re) {        
    // tons of html is printed here
}
echo " }";
```

So the question is, how do I most effectively send back a whole gang of html code, along with some variables that can be easily eval'ed by JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) This will eliminate any errors you might have in trying to create your own json.

```
$returnArray = array(
    'status'=>'success',
    'total' => count($relevance),
    'data' => ''
);

foreach ($relevance as $re) {        
    $returnArray['data'] .= $re; // + all long html code
}

echo json_encode($returnArray);
```

Comment: @Pointy into the `$returnArray['data']`

Comment: So elegant! Love it and it worked perfectly. I have no idea why I haven't been using json_encode all the time. Damn memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can encode the data as JSON and then put it in a `<script>` block that's got a non-JavaScript type.  Give the script a class too so your code can look for it easily. You can then get the ".innerHTML" of the `<script>` element and decode the JSON. Then just add the `<script>` to the rest of the HTML you're returning.

*edit* No use @Neal's answer instead; it's a less goofy idea. I've done what I've described but usually that's because for some other (framework) reason it's not easy (or just inconvenient) to get directly at the 
response data. Also, I generally generate pages via JSP, so it's much easier to drop JSON into a page than to get the page contents into Java.

To elaborate, a `<script>` block like this:

```
<script type='text/json' class='some-data-for-you'>
  { "hello": "world" }
</script>
```

will be ignored by the browser because the "type" won't be recognized as code.  Then your JavaScript code can just look for `<script>` elements with class "some-data-for-you" in the returned content and then parse the ".innerHTML" with a JSON parser.

Comment: It's a common trick, used for example to "hide" stuff when using a JavaScript templating system. If the type of the `<script>` is "text/json" or anything else that's **not** a type the browser recognizes as meaning, "This is JavaScript", then it just ignores the contents of the tag.

Comment: Ha ha yes it scared me when I first saw it in a John Resig blog post, but once I got over that I found that it's a really clean way of doing certain things. Like anything else it could be badly abused, I suppose.

Comment: You have a link to the post by any chance?

Comment: [Here is where he talks about the technique in the context of templating.](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)